# repaint() method is not functioning as expected

Tags: java, repaint

I have the following class, DrawStatus which is responsible for making a drawing, adding it to a panel, and then that panel is added to another panel inside a frame. This issue I am having is that I have a button, and an actionlistener for that button that calls the changeWarningLightColor() method and inside this method the warnColor is supposed to change and then change the color of rectangles in the drawing but the color never changes. I have verified with my print statement that this method is getting called, but the drawing does not update/get repainted because the color does not change. I would like to know if I am not using the repaint() method properly, or what the correct way to accomplish what I want would be.

```
public class DrawStatus extends JPanel{
     Status status = new Status();
     Color pedLights=Color.RED;
     Color warnColor=Color.GREEN;
     JPanel panel;

public DrawStatus(){

}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int height = getHeight(); 
    int width = getWidth();
    int midpointX = ((width-800)+width-400)/2;

    g.setColor(warnColor);
    g.fillRect(midpointX-45, (height-300)+5, 15, 15);
    g.fillRect(midpointX-45, (height-400)-18, 15, 15);
    g.fillRect(midpointX+30, (height-300)+5, 15, 15);
    g.fillRect(midpointX+30, (height-400)-18, 15, 15);

}


public void changeWarningLightColor(){
    System.out.println("change color method called");
    if(warnColor.equals(Color.GREEN)){
        warnColor=Color.RED;
        repaint();

    }
    else{
        warnColor=Color.GREEN;
        repaint();  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted should work, sounds like problem is else where

Comment: This drawing is added to another panel in a different class as `LeftSidePanel.add(new DrawStatus(),BorderLayout.CENTER);` perhaps the problem is in that class

Comment: So, you use new DrawStatus() to add the componet to the screen, but maintain no reference to the component so you can update it later? So what are you actually updating?

Comment: To reprhase MadProgrammers comment: You are obviously creating *two* instances of the `DrawStatus` class: One instance that you are adding with the line that you posted. The other instance is created somehwere else. And you are calling the `changeWarningLightColor` method on this other instance (and **not** on the instance that is visible on the screen)

Comment: I think I may know why that is, originally when the program first starts there is an instance to draw the rectangles, then when the button is pressed that is a different instance because it is from a different class. Is it possible to share the instances between classes?

Comment: ez, yes, pass a reference of the active, visible DrawStatus  instance into where it is needed. Constructor or setter method parameters work well for ths.

Comment: got everything working now as expected. Thanks

Comment: Nice going and thanks for letting us know.